# SQL to query chronological event list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is the table content. Each row is related to the other by the Event:

```
Id Style    BeginDate BeginEvent   EndDate   EndEvent**

1  Style-2  1/1/2001  Manufacture  3/1/2001  Colorchange
1  Style-2  3/1/2001  Colorchange  5/1/2001  StyleChange
1  Style-3  5/1/2001  StyleChange  10/1/2001 Sold
```

Need a query that can provide the following output:

```
Id, Previous_Style, New_Style, Change_Date
```

In essence, I want to find out when a style change happened based on the chronological events in the table.

Thanks !

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? Some databases support window functions, some don't. Do you have gaps between end and begin date of another event?

Comment: This is SQL Server 2012. There might be gaps and overlaps on the dates, but the actual events are the best indicators of a connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `lag()` and filtering.  From what I can tell:

```
select id, prevStyle, Style, BeginDate
from (select t.*,
             lag(style) over (partition by id order by begindate) as prevStyle
      from t
     ) t
where BeginEvent = 'StyleChange';
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But what if I have a style and a substyle and want to take both into consideration?

Comment: You can call `lag()` twice.  If that doesn't work, ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can join to itself using the id and the end/start date.

```
select t1.id
, t2.style as previousstyle
, t1.style as newstyle
, t1.begindate as changedate
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.enddate = t1.begindate
    and t2.style <> t1.style
```

Comment: You probably want to include endevent/beginevent in the join too.